# Shortcut Assign to Return Triggers Enter

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

I assigned a Shortcut in multiline textbox which is <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Return</kbd>.

It works but, when I use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Return</kbd>, <kbd>Enter</kbd> button triggers and makes cursor go to bottom line. How can I disable <kbd>Enter</kbd> when I press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Return</kbd>?

```
if (e.Control==true && e.KeyCode == Keys.Return)
 {
        // do anything()
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

This is just a shot in the dark, but will it work to add the following inside the if statement?

```
e.Cancel = true;
```

Comment: there is no 'Cancel' properties.

Comment: Sorry, I don't know then.

Answer (score 0):

Using below command will work;

```
if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Enter)
   {
     e.SuppressKeyPress = true;
   }
```

Answer (score 0):

If I recall correctly, keydown event will fire after the textbox receives the character.

Try keypress event instead:

```
        private void textBox1_KeyPress(object sender, KeyPressEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.KeyChar == '\n')
        {
            // do anything()
            e.Handled = true;
        }
    }
```